# cv2.Laplacian vs cv2.filter2d - Different results

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, convolution, laplacian

I am trying to convolve my grayscale image with various filters. I have used the

```
cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F)
```

and

```
kernel =np.array([[0, 1, 0] , [1, -4, 1] , [0, 1, 0]])
dst = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, kernel)
```

But the results are different.

Can someone elaborate why I am getting different results?

Answer (score 1):

Since what the implementation of `cv2.Laplacian` does in that case is exactly to convolve with the `[[0, 1, 0], [1, -4, 1], [0, 1, 0]]` filter as you do, it seems that the likely culprit is the datatype that your are feeding to `cv2.Filter2D`.

By using this code

```
kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0] , [1, -4, 1] , [0, 1, 0]])
dst1 = cv2.filter2D(im, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, kernel=kernel)
dst2 = cv2.Laplacian(im, cv2.CV_64F)
```

you should get

```
>>> np.all(dst1==dst2)
True
```